# Calculate the mean and the use of list lead to lost time property

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to output charts of mean NDVI per month, but calculate the mean and the use of list lead to lost time property. And I don't kown how to copy property.

```
//渲染Layer显示颜色
var vis = {min: -0.2, max: 1, palette: [
  'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'FCD163', '66A000', '207401',
  '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011301'
]};

//定义图表中不同作物类型的颜色
var COLOR = {
  LINDI: 'ff0000',
  GENGDI: '0000ff'
};
//定义感兴趣区
var lindi = ee.Feature(   
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(115.105882, 35.430421,115.106077, 35.430255),
    {label: 'LINDI'});
var gengdi = ee.Feature(  
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(115.104388, 35.430467, 115.10501, 35.429855),
    {label: 'GENGDI'});

//将作物感兴趣区合并
var cropRegions = new ee.FeatureCollection([lindi,gengdi]);

//去云
var s2_rmcloud = function(image) {
 var quality = image.select("QA60").unmask();
 return image.updateMask(quality.eq(0));
};
//compute ndvi
function NDVI(image) {
 return image.select().addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).select([0], ['NDVI'])
 .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']));}
var start_list=new Array('2018-1-1','2018-2-1','2018-3-1','2018-4-1','2018-5-1','2018-6-1',
      '2018-7-1','2018-8-1','2018-9-1','2018-10-1','2018-11-1','2018-12-1');
var end_list=new Array('2018-2-1','2018-3-1','2018-4-1','2018-5-1','2018-6-1','2018-7-1',
    '2018-8-1','2018-9-1','2018-10-1','2018-11-1','2018-12-1','2019-1-1');

var test=[];
for (var i=0; i<start_list.length; i++)
{ 
  var s2= ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
 .filterDate('2018-1-1', '2019-1-1')
 .filterDate(start_list[i], end_list[i])
 .filterBounds(cropRegions);

var s2 = s2.map(s2_rmcloud)

//筛选s2数据

for (var i=0; i<start_list.length; i++)
{ 
  var s2= ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
 .filterDate(start_list[i], end_list[i])
 .filterBounds(cropRegions);

var s2 = s2.map(s2_rmcloud)
//计算每副影像的NDVI并制作数据集
var ndvi = s2.map(NDVI);
//Map.addLayer(ndvi, vis, 'NDVI_'+i);

test.push(ndvi.mean().copyProperties(ndvi));
//Map.addLayer(test,vis,'NDVI_average');
//print("test", test)
}

  var test = ee.ImageCollection(test)
var ndviTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: test,
  regions: cropRegions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  band: 'NDVI',
  scale: 10,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  seriesProperty: 'label'
});
ndviTimeSeries.setChartType('ScatterChart');
ndviTimeSeries.setOptions({
  title: 'Sentinel-2数据作物时间序列NDVI变化',
  vAxis: {
    title: 'NDVI'
  },
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 4,
  series: {
    0: {color: COLOR.LINDI},
    1: {color: COLOR.GENGDI},
  }
});

Map.addLayer(cropRegions, {color: COLOR.LINDI},'ROI');
Map.centerObject(cropRegions, 8)
// Map.addLayer(lindi, {color: COLOR.LINDI});
// Map.addLayer(gengdi, {color: COLOR.GENDDI});
print(ndviTimeSeries)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that

```
test.push(ndvi.mean().copyProperties(ndvi));
```

does not make much sense because "ndvi" at this point is an image collection and it is trying to copy properties of an image collection onto a newly create image "ndvi.mean()". Since you are already within a loop that is using start and end time to filter the image, i think the easiest way to insert the start time information would be to use that start time and insert a date object

```
test.push(ndvi.mean().set('system:time_start',ee.Date(start_list[i])));
```

Also, I don't know if it was present in the code or a mistake while copying but there is a **}** missing after the above line. (There is 1 but there should be 2)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
Sorry, copy the code is wrong.
'''test.push(ndvi.mean().copyProperties(ndvi));'''
It shouldn't have,'. CopyProerties (ndvi)', because I don't understand the image into ImageCollection mechanism, this mechanism can explain?
Why not , this code ?
'''var test = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(test).set("system:time_start", ee.Date(start_list[0]).millis());'''

Under the "} "the following sentences, because want to make the first image list, this list ImageCollection.

Comment: well technically you can copy properties from image collection to an image BUT an image collection generally does not have the information on start time as it is the scan start time for that scene.
`var test = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(test).set("system:time_start", ee.Date(start_list[0]).millis());`  well there are a few things wrong with this. 1st you are refering the object "test" before defining it. Also, you dont need "millis()" the constructor should generate millis using the date supplied.

Comment: Thank you very much for you can point out my questions patiently.I already know.